# OpenEJB 4.6.0 does not start with jdk8

Tags: java-8, openejb

I'm using OpenEJB in my JUnit tests. It worked fine with jdk7. Unfortunately, it does not start with jdk1.8.0. Any ideas?

```
C:\javaapps\jdk1.8.0\bin\java 
...    
10:31:11 SEVERE org.apache.openejb.util.OpenEJBErrorHandler handleUnknownError FATAL ERROR: Unknown error in Assembler.  Please send the following stack trace and this message to users@openejb.apache.org :
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm4.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm4.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm4.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.openejb.util.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:297)
    at org.apache.openejb.util.AnnotationFinder.find(AnnotationFinder.java:163)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.checkAnnotations(DeploymentLoader.java:1871)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.discoverModuleType(DeploymentLoader.java:1782)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentsResolver.processUrls(DeploymentsResolver.java:388)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentsResolver.loadFromClasspath(DeploymentsResolver.java:301)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.getModulesFromClassPath(ConfigurationFactory.java:647)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.getOpenEjbConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:524)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.getOpenEjbConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:575)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.getOpenEjbConfiguration(Assembler.java:429)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.build(Assembler.java:408)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init>(OpenEJB.java:148)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.<init>(OpenEJB.java:65)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB.init(OpenEJB.java:296)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB.init(OpenEJB.java:276)
```

Comment: well, send the message to the openejb devs as it says :)

Answer (score 1):

yeah, asm used is not compatible with java 8 yeat, should be the case pretty soon btw, hope to get it for 4.7.0

Comment: Thanks for the answer and looking forward to 4.7.0 then... :-)

Comment: asm 5.0.1 was the first release of asm to support java 8

Answer (score 0):

i would guess that the asm library supplied with EJB is not java8 compatible. the java class file format has some new features, and it looks like asm4 is having some problems with it.